# installing a font when page is opened

Tags: html, fonts

i have a font that already installed in my system, in Firefox I've set an `div` with `font-family:'fontname'` and the font isn't applied on the `div` , but in Chrome or IE it's working.

Comment: Add full syntax of what you have, preferably with JSFiddle sample. And try to play around with font-style property, in some cases it is meaningful.

Comment: How does the title relate to the question?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [@font-face](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp) propriety to load new fonts, you can use [font squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to transform the computer font !

Comment: i've tried this:

@font-face {
    font-family: 'font';
    src: url("images/FS_Metal.ttf");
}

.menu_head {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    font-family: 'font';
}

Answer (score 0):

If you want using font, you must upload it to web directory, for other users which havent this font, or use web fonts and change CSS file only.

Take font here: http://www.google.com/webfonts/

Then iclude it in CSS-file

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans);
```

And use with Div:

```
div { font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif; }
```